# @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS

Tags: java, android, libc

I am developing an biometric reader android application.

I am getting following error when specific user punches his finger against the biometric reader.

```
06-19 17:11:31.684 11322-11331/com.cms.attendance A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x68841118
06-19 17:11:31.684 11322-11331/com.cms.attendance A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 11331 (FinalizerDaemon)
06-19 17:11:32.324 2127-2322/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '425ec358 com.cms.attendance/com.cms.attendance.fingerprintreader.newui.DashboardActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

The method which makes calls to the biometric reader is `synchronized`.
I have been trying to solve this issue since last week without any success.

There is no specific line on which this error is observed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You have all the code at hand, the environment to debug it. We on the other hand just have those 3 lines of log messages. So how exactly do you think we would be able to help you here?! And just to clarify: you are saying that the error only happens for a *specific* user? (if so, the user probably has a virus added to his finger prints, confusing the hardware). Seriously: this could be anything. A hardware bug, in the firmware of mobile or reader, anything.